# Docker for Windows stuck at "Kubernetes is Starting" after updating to version 2.1.1.0 Edge (or Stable)

Tags: windows, docker, kubernetes

I recently updated my Docker for Desktop to latest Edge channel version: 2.1.1.0 on a Windows 10 machine. Unfortunately, after updating, Kubernetes was no longer working as it is always stuck at "Kubernetes is Starting".

I have tried the following so far.

- Restarting Docker
- Resetting the Kubernetes Cluster
- Restoring Factory Default settings
- Restarting machine
- Uninstalling and reinstalling Docker

Nothing seems to be working. How can I resolve it?

Comment: The GitHub [docker/for-mac](https://github.com/docker/for-mac) project is probably a better place for generic support requests.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

After hours of trying out different things, here is what finally helped me:

1. Restore Docker to Factory Default settings and Quit Docker for Desktop
2. Delete the folder `C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\pki` (Make a backup of it just in case). Note that many have reported the folder to be located elsewhere: `C:\Users\<user_name>\AppData\Local\Docker\pki`
3. Delete the folder `~\.kube\` (Again make a backup to be safe)
4. Start Docker again, open Docker settings, make the necessary configuration changes (adding proxy, setting resource limits, etc..), Enable Kubernetes and let it start
5. Wait a while and both Docker and Kubernetes will be up now.

When you try to connect to Kubernetes using kubectl, you might face another issue like

```
Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

You can solve this by

1. Open ~.kube\config in a text editor
2. Replace `https://kubernetes.docker.internal:6443` to `https://localhost:6443`
3. Try connecting again.

Or if you are behind a (corporate) proxy: add `kubernetes.docker.internal` to `NO_PROXY` (eg `export NO_PROXY=kubernetes.docker.internal`), given that the proxy is configured correctly.

If this still doesn't resolve your issue, go through the logs at   `C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\log\` to debug the issue further

Comment: Where exactly is ~\.kube\? I couldn't find such directory.

Comment: That's Linux parlance for your home directory (usually: C:\users\<your user name>). In Linux, the tilde character is a shortcut for your home directory. Irshad P I was possibly using a Linux shell on Windows, which is why he/she answered that way.

Comment: I had a similar issue (Docker 2.0.0.3 (31259)) on Windows 10 (1909) and was able to get Kubernetes running following these steps.

Comment: On macOS (10.14.6), I reset to docker desktop (v 2.2.2.0) to factory settings, deleted ~/.docker and ~/.kube, restarted the desktop, enabled k8s and it worked as described in the answer.

Comment: My logs where under: C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Local\Docker\log.txt.

Comment: I have done as this answer has suggested but that did not solve it for me. Apparently, it was searching in the wrong place for the .kube\config file. So I added an environment variable with the name KUBECONFIG and value "C:\Users\<your user name>\.kube\config". Then, on the toolbar icon of the Docker App I have selected Quit Docker Desktop and then I have manually started it via the exe. Kubernetes has afterwards starter running and has changed to green state. By running "kubectl config current-context" I could now see the docker-desktop context. I hope that this will be of help for someone.

Comment: use powershell on windows to get cd ~/.kube then start . to open in GUI

Comment: I solved it with Docker Desktop Community 2.2.0, refer more https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/5442

Comment: This also fixed it for me on a Mac. The pki file was in a different spot on Mac, so I used [this command](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/3594#issuecomment-621487150) to delete it: `rm -rf ~/Library/Group\ Containers/group.com.docker/pki/ `

Comment: The fix that worked for me is firstly I deleted config.lock file and then pki folder, I was not able to find the pki folder in my local user, had to login through admin right.

Comment: I couldn't find the ~\.kube location on windows and just deleted C:\Users\<user_name>\AppData\Local\Docker\pki folder and it worked for me

Answer (score 38):

I recommend you to check your etc/hosts file to have following lines.

```
127.0.0.1       docker-for-desktop
127.0.0.1       kubernetes.docker.internal
```

Because docker is failing to resolve your localhost and it get stucks on that state.

And Are you behind some corporate proxy? If so try to switch your proxy or try to bypass it the first time you start the K8. 
I had the same problem and 
This solved my issue actually not the upgrading or downgrading.

Comment: thank you very much. For some reason, my hosts file was overwritten and this answer was the exact solution needed.

Comment: Antivir is blocking changes in hosts files. This solved my problem.

Comment: I just added kubernetes.docker.internal to etc/hosts and it worked

Comment: Weird that Docker Desktop added host.docker.internal, gateway.docker.internal and kubernetes.docker.internal to HOSTS but not docker-for-desktop. That was the missing key that got Kubernetes installed and started for me.

Comment: bingo! just add "127.0.0.1 docker-for-desktop"("127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal is already there"),  it works!

Answer (score 20):

Irshad's solution worked for me. In my case, pki dir was in 
C:\Users\<user_name>\AppData\Local\Docker

Answer (score 7):

I was facing this today and spent couple of hours trying to fix. First thing is to find out why it keeps hanging in starting. You can find the reason by checking the logs at **C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop**. There will be some service.txt files, open the recently modified one.

For me the issue was this,

```
[19:32:58.189][ApiProxy][Error] time="2020-01-20T19:32:58+13:00" msg="Cannot list nodes: Get https://kubernetes.docker.internal:6443/api/v1/nodes: EOF"
```

Once the issue is known, then we can easily fix it. I have to removed the folder named **pki** inside **C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop** (as mentioned in [issues/4316](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/4316)) and restarted the docker.

Now it's all good. This might not be the reason for all the hangs at starting, but checking the logs will definitely help out.

Hope this helps!

Comment: On my windows, the folder and file is not on DockerDesktop but (via gitbash): ~/AppData/Local/Docker/log.txt

Answer (score 6):

What worked for me based on info at https://forums.docker.com/t/waiting-for-kubernetes-to-be-up-and-running/47009:

1. Reset Docker to factory settings
2. Quit Docker
3. Set the KUBECONFIG environment variable to %USERPROFILE%\.kube\config
4. Restart Docker and enable Kubernetes (still took a few minutes to start)

Comment: Correct value for path is "%USERPROFILE%\.kube\config".

Comment: using powershell on windows # cd ~\.kube\config

Comment: I initially had a minikube installation and I'd deleted this. So my steps were: 
1. reset docker-desktop
2. delete my existing `%USERPROFILE%\.kube\config`
3. Enable Kubernetes in docker-desktop again
4. Wait about 3-5 mins
This seems to have fixed it. Thank you for you answer

Answer (score 5):

For me docker was starting and kubernetes was stuck in `Starting`.

Irshad's solution worked for me as well by just removing `pki` folder.

Folder location for Windows: `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Docker\pki`.

Answer (score 4):

I faced the problem with Docker Desktop 2.4.0 on Windows 10.
The log file was in a different location -

> C:\Users<user name>\AppData\Local\Docker\log.txt

Log files always tell the real situation. In my case, I had manually edited the

> C:\Users<user name>.kube\config yaml file

and had messed up the spaces and tabs. On correcting it, it started smoothly !

Answer (score 3):

My problem was fixed following the next steps:

1. Go to `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`
2. Right click on hosts file and go to Properties
3. Disable **Read-Only Mode**
4. Reinstall docker

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking how at least disable Kubernetes and reset button don't help:

1. Click on "Reset Kubernetes Cluster"
2. Restart docker (Kubernetes status on the left corner must be red now)
3. Clear "Enable Kubernetes" checkbox
4. Restart docker again.

Answer (score 1):

Check the log file at
`%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Docker\log.txt`

In my case I found that kubernetes wouldn't reinstall because I had renamed the    directory
`%USERPROFILE%\.kube`
in order to start from scratch.

However the environment variable `KUBECONFIG` was still set, and was referring to a set of concatenated config files which no longer existed.

To fix the issue I deleted the environment variable,
and then reinstalled kubernetes through the docker desktop ui.
This recreated the `%USERPROFILE%\.kube\config`

I then restored the other config files and recreated the variable `KUBECONFIG` with the concatenated values.

Answer (score 0):

Went through each answer above and this is the only one that fixed it for me!

It contains some of the stuff above, but it is important to clean up all the files, otherwise, it doesn't get fixed

1 uninstall docker
2 Inside of your windows user folder , delete following

```
.kube
.docker
```

3 Delete **docker** and **dockerDesktop** in **ProgramData**

C: \ Users \ user\ AppData \ Local
C: \ user\ raffaeler \ AppData \ Roaming

4 Installing latest Docker

5  Then only activate Kubernetes, not the other options.

Keep on watching the following log files to known the progress. For me it took lot of time for kubernetes to come up.

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Docker\log.txt
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Docker\log\vm\kubelet.log
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Docker\log\vm\dockerd.log
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the reason of the problem was one more entry in hosts file above the line

`127.0.0.1       kubernetes.docker.internal`

it was

`127.0.0.1       acme.com`

this localhost allocation blocks k8s starting

Answer (score 0):

(latest version)

This thing happens to me whenever I update Docker,

the following has helped me

1)I restarted the Docker engine by Turning the Power button on the Bottom left.

2. Clean/purge the Wsl, Hyper V,  and windows containers and Reseting the K8s Clusters

Hope this works for you

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35530533)